# How can I implement multiple RadioListTile in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to display a multiple choice quiz in my Flutter app. I am getting the data from my server and displaying each question an option in my client. I would like to select 1 option for each question and have an array of these selections to send it back to my client.

This is how I am displaying them in my client, storing them on a string to further add them to a list and how I am trying to use the RadioListTile:

```
class _QuizViewer extends State<QuizViewer> {
  String option1 = '';
  String option2 = '';
  String option3 = '';
  List<String> options = [];
  List<int> selectedvalue = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Quizzes>>(
      future: fetchQuizzes(widget.quizid),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('No hay quizzes publicados'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Quizzes disponibles'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
            ),
            body: new ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                if (selectedvalue.length == 0) {
                  for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data!.length; i++) {
                    selectedvalue.add(0);
                  }
                }
                return Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Text('${snapshot.data![index].question}'),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      RadioListTile(
                        value: snapshot.data![index].solucion1,
                        title: Text('${snapshot.data![index].solucion1}'),
                        onChanged: (val) => setState(() {
                          //selectedvalue[index] = int.parse(val.toString());
                          option1 = snapshot.data![index].solucion1;
                          print(selectedvalue);
                          print(option1);
                        }),
                        groupValue: selectedvalue[index],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      RadioListTile(
                        value: snapshot.data![index].solucion2,
                        title: Text('${snapshot.data![index].solucion2}'),
                        onChanged: (val) => setState(() {
                          //selectedvalue[index] = int.parse(val.toString());
                          option2 = snapshot.data![index].solucion2;
                          print(selectedvalue);
                          print(option2);
                        }),
                        groupValue: selectedvalue[index],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      RadioListTile(
                        value: snapshot.data![index].solucion3,
                        title: Text('${snapshot.data![index].solucion3}'),
                        onChanged: (val) => setState(() {
                          //selectedvalue[index] = int.parse(val.toString());
                          option3 = snapshot.data![index].solucion3;
                          print(selectedvalue);
                          print(option3);
                        }),
                        groupValue: selectedvalue[index],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                onPressed: () {
                  options.add(option1);
                  options.add(option2);
                  options.add(option3);
                  print(options);
                },
                label: Text('Mis entregas')),
          );
        } else {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('No hay quizzes publicados'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

However, when I select any option on any of the questions it get selected on the other questions as well... so I am not able to individually select them. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of int selectedValue use a list of int.
`List<int> selectedValue = [];`

In the List.Builder add a 0 to this list

```
   if(selectedValue.length == 0)
        {
            for(int i  = 0; i < snapshot.data!.length; i ++)
           {
               selected value.add(0);
            }
        }
```

For each option assign different values. For example for the first option

```
 value: snapshot.data![index].option1
```

Assign this value in groupValue

`groupValue = selectedValue[index]`

The issue is you are assigning a single value to all questions so it selects for all questions.

Comment: I updated as you mentioned (the question has also been updated accordingly), which totally makes sense what youre saying... but now I get  this error: `RangeError(index): Index out of range: no indces are valid: 0`. The error is on this line `selectedvalue[index] = 0;`. Most likely I added in the wrong place...

Comment: this is because initially there is no value. Instead of `selectedvalue[index] = 0;` try this selectedValue.add(0);

Comment: The values are now showing but when I select 1 option all 3 get selected and `selectedValues` keeps increasing its size

Comment: Okay we are really close now! I will be updating the code with your new recommendation. It is storing the values and printing them successfully. But now its not updating the selection, it throws a `gesture error` in this line `onChanged: (val) => setState(() {//selectedvalue[index] = int.parse(val.toString());`. I believe I am updating the state of `selectedValue` incorrectly. Guess that is the only thing missing. You will see the updated code.